# 2001 Lincoln continental engine whirring and shaking whole car

Tags: engine, lincoln, continental

I’m not sure what the problem is. I have a 2001 Lincoln continental and the engine seems to be whirring and shakes the whole car in reverse/drive/park/neutral. It has no engine lights, no codes, nothing. I tried unplugging the MAF sensor and there’s no change in the idle. What could be the problem???

Here is a YouTube video of the noise

https://youtu.be/RcwtzRiDJCE

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked for codes at all? Have you looked at any live data to see what the computer is telling you? Have you tried to run some injector cleaner through it (Seafoam, BG44K, or the like ... not a little bottle of STP or similar)? When was the last time a tune up was done on the car? You pulled the MAF to check, but have you tried cleaning it with electronics cleaner?

Comment: I checked the codes with a scanner and I didn’t get any. Does t all. I also checked the live data for all 8 cylinders and it doesn’t seem like any are misfiring which is why I don’t think it’s spark plugs. I didn’t try cleaning the MAF sensor yet. I read online if you unplug the MAF sensor and the car stops, it’s working as it should. If you unplug and it still runs or it still runs but idles differently, then it’s a bad MAF sensor. Is that true? And how do I run injector cleaner through it?

Comment: Pour injector cleaner directly into the tank (at fillup). Love data also includes how the O2s read and whatever else you can look at. On the MAF, it depends on the vehicle, but usually just unplugging it should force it 8nto speed density mode, so really doesnt give you much info.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What I actually ended up doing was I sprayed the MAF sensor and the IAC with cleaner because it was so dusty and the car was from Texas, which makes sense. The car isles fine now and it’s no problem anymore